# How to modify file fist 256kb without creating a new file and copying?

Tags: java, android, encryption, file-io

I am downloading some file Audio/Video/PDF from amazon S3 server. What I am doing is at the start of download encrypt the only first 256kb for each file.
Recently I add resume functionality. What I want to do is to wait for complete downloading of file. One completed then I will encrypt the frist 256kb of file.

> I want to encrypt first 256kb of file without creating a new file for that. As if I create a new then after 256kb I have to copy the other bytes to new file. This will take time as file size can be 200MB to 500MB.

What is the best solution for that?
I am using JDK1.6 Downloading is via input/output stream.

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
```

Comment: Please post your code snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use [RandomAccessFile](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html). Read your 250K, encrypt on memory, overwrite in the same file.

Comment: This is looking useful. Can you please tell me one this. I will read 256kb using public int read (byte[] buffer, int offset, int count).
But will public void write (byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) append the new bytes???? OR replace the old bytes in that range? I am confused about this?

Comment: Read the JavaDoc please, it's quite informative. You can move the current pointer using seek(). If you move it to any place besides the end of the file, you will overwrite the current contents when you call `write()`.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Let me check this.

Answer (score 1):

Other option is to create your own CustomInputStream class which extends InputStream. When you are reading from your customInputStream keep the count of bytes read as soon as read bytes reaches 256 you can decrypt them then onwords you can just call super.read() method.